# How to create List of list of atoms in scheme

Tags: scheme

I installed scheme on macOS. I am reading "little schemer" and want to create a list of list of atoms which looks like

```
((how much (wood)) could ((a (wood) chuck)) (((chuck))) (if (a) ((wood chuck))) could chuck wood)
```

to create this list I tried the following code

```
(define x '((how much (wood)) could ((a (wood) chuck)) (((chuck))) (if (a) ((wood chuck))) could chuck wood))
```

but now when I say

```
(display car(x))
```

I get an error

```
1 ]=> (display car(x))

;The object ((how much (wood)) could ((a (wood) chuck)) (((chuck))) (if (a) ((wood chuck))) could chuck wood) is not applicable.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 2) => Specify a procedure to use in its place.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
2 error>
```

why can't I do `car` on my list? is it that it's not built correctly and so I cannot do `car` on it?

also tried

```
2 error> (display (car(x)))

;The object ((how much (wood)) could ((a (wood) chuck)) (((chuck))) (if (a) ((wood chuck))) could chuck wood) is not applicable.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 3) => Specify a procedure to use in its place.
; (RESTART 2) => Return to read-eval-print level 2.
```

; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

Comment: Try `(display (car x))`. This is C style: `display (car (x))`. You can not mix them.

Comment: The LIttle Schemer does not say that `car (x)` is a procedure call.

Comment: @ceving i tried (display (car(x))) but still same error

Answer (score 0):

OK got the answer (thanks to @molbdnilo for his/her comment above).

```
(display (car x))
```

Comment: `car` is an application. Because of this, it has parenthesis. But `x` is not a "function call". Because of that, it does not have parenthesis. Schemers say "application" and not "function call", because `(define a 1)` is an application but not a function call, because `define` is not a function but syntax.

Comment: got it. yes. parentheses in lisp are for application of functions. not for wrapping parameters (like other programming languages).